# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' to 'NSData'

Tags: swift, alamofire, jsondecoder

I'm trying to decode the following data:

```
AF.upload(postData!, to: loginUrlString, headers: postmanManager.headers).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)
            do {
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: value as! Data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let id = results.Usuario[0].Id
                    let name = results.Usuario[0].Name

                    let userInfo = UserModel(Id: id, firstName: name)
                    print(userInfo)
                }
            } catch {
            print(error)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

The 'User' object belongs to the following struct:

```
struct User: Codable {
let Usuario: [UserData]
}

struct UserData: Codable {
let Id: Int
let Name: String
}
```

I tried looking up the answer and from what I understood, I tried changing `value as! Data` to `value as! [String: Any]`, but I get another error:

`Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'`

What else could I try changing? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong response type.

Replace

```
.responseJSON
```

with

```
.responseData
```

And please name functions and variables with starting lowercase letter.